# A contest math problem involving work schedules and work rate

Tags: contest-math

The problem is:

*It takes Danny 18 hours to complete a job alone, Ian 24 hours alone, and Roy 30 hours alone. If the three people work in the following seqence: Danny => Ian => Roy => Ian => Roy => Danny => Roy => Danny => Ian. Each person works for 1 hour in a session. This schedule repeats every 9 turns until the job is done. At the end, how many hours did Danny, Ian and Roy work when the job is done respectively?*

I have only thought of a brute-force approach to this problem, which is rather slow.

Any other way to solve this problem?

Edit: I used some hints given in the comments, below is my work:

*Each nine-turn round would give us*

*$\frac{20+15+12}{360}\times3 = \frac{141}{360}$ of the total work
if the whole job is "one"*

*Then after two rounds of work, we would have $\frac{78}{360}$ of the total work left to be done.*
*Now all three workers have 6 hours of work time.*

*Now note Danny gets $\frac{20}{360}$ or total work done each turn(per hour), Ian gets $\frac{15}{360}$ and Roy gets $\frac{12}{360}$*

*Cycle from the start. After three turns(hours) we'd have $\frac{31}{360}$ more. All three workers have 7 hours of work time*

*Now after the next person Ian we'd have $\frac{16}{360}$ more...*

*Next is Roy, after him is $\frac{4}{360}$ more.*

*Lastly, it only takes Danny 4/20 = 0.2 hours to finish off all the work.*

*So we have it! 8 hours for Ian and Roy while Danny works for $7+0.2 = 7.2$ hours*

Comment: Which contest is this for? Also, is this from an on-going contest?

Comment: Hint: think about what proportion of the job each of them gets done in an hour. For example, if it takes me $x$ hours to do a job, I can get $\frac{1}{x}$ of the job done in 1 hour.

Comment: I'd first figure out how much work the triple gets done in a $3$ hour cycle.  Then figure out how many who cycles are needed, and adjust the stub.

Comment: @SohamKonar No worries, it's not on-going. This is a 7th grader WMI competition problem a few years ago.

Comment: @Cyh1368 Have you gotten it yet? I can post my solution if you want.

Comment: @SohamKonar I have used some hints given by you guys and got a solution: 8, $7\frac{11}{24}$, 7 hours for Danny, Ian and Roy respectively. But that wasn't the answer given by the contest officials (7.2, 8, 8 hours respectively)

Comment: Maybe you're looking at the wrong cycle because there are three different cycles (D-I-R, I-R-D, R-D-I) and that would affect the end of the answer and judging from your answer it looks like you did choose the wrong cycle but I can also tell that you are definitely on the right path.

Comment: @SohamKonar I checked my original solution and I found that I mis-calculated the work hours and the cycle. I have posted my solution in the post, which got the right answer.

Comment: @Cyh1368 Well done! That's exactly how I did it :)